# double free when freeing structure in array

Tags: c, arrays, memory-management

I'm reading a file line by line (the file only contains one line for testing) and I'm creating a `struct` for every line, and adding that `struct` to a predefined array.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>


typedef struct {
    int age;
    int weight;
    char *name;
} Person;


int person_create(Person **person, unsigned int age, unsigned int weight, char *name)
{   
    *person = malloc(sizeof(Person));

    if (person == NULL) {
        return 0;
    }

    return 1;
}

void person_free(Person *person)
{
    free(person);

    return;
}

int main(void)
{
    FILE *input_file = NULL;

    input_file = fopen("names.txt", "r");
    assert(input_file != NULL);

    char *line = NULL;
    size_t _ = 0;
    ssize_t line_len = 0;
    Person persons[1] = {};
    int line_num = 0;

    while ((line_len = getline(&line, &_, input_file)) != -1) {
        if (line[line_len - 1] == '\n') {
            line[line_len - 1] = '\0';  
        }

        Person *person = NULL;
        person_create(&person, line_num, 2, line);

        persons[line_num] = *person;

        line_num++;        
    }

    free(line);

    printf("lines read %d\n", line_num);

    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        person_free(&persons[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I stripped the program down as far as I could, but upon free'ing the array entry, I get an error

```
*** Error in `./prog': double free or corruption (out): 0x00007fff7ace9f10 ***
Aborted (core dumped)
```

If I leave out the call to `free_person` then `valgrind` reports lost memory.

I'm pretty sure it has to do with how I assign the person for each line to the array

```
    Person *person = NULL;
    person_create(&person, line_num, 2, line);

    persons[line_num] = *person;
```

But I can't seem to understand what exactly is going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program has some serious undefined behavior: once `line_num` gets above zero, you are writing into memory *outside* `persons[]` array. You need to allocate enough elements, and also make it an array of pointers:

```
Person *persons[100]; // or some other MAX
```

Once you make `persons[]` an array of pointers, it becomes clear why `free(&persons[i])` and `persons[line_num] = *person` are incorrect (the compiler should issue a warning for the assignment).

In addition, this check of `malloc` result is incorrect:

```
if (person == NULL) {
    return 0;
}
```

You should check `*person`, not `person`, because `person` is a double pointer.

Comment: OK, I agree. Its of course only a dummy program, because I want to learn how to work with dynamic memory allocation, like who owns the memory and who is responsible for freeing … I take your point though and totally agree.

Comment: Thank you for also pointing out the other flaws. I have a lot to learn.

Answer (score 1):

You're losing the `malloc()`ed memory, since you copy it into your array of actual structures (`persons`). Your code doesn't need to use `malloc()`, and certainly not `free()` like it does.

It would make more sense to have an array of pointers:

```
Person *persons[10];
```

Then have the function that calls `malloc()` return the newly allocated memory, so you can do `persons[line_num] = person_create(line_num, 2, line);`. *Then* you need to go through and `free()` them all.

Comment: The point of my program is that I want to learn how to use dynamic memory allocation, I know it probably looks a bit weird/superfluous. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your code shows undefined behaviour. You've decalred

```
 Person persons[1] = {};
```

and later, you're using

```
persons[line_num] = *person;
```

which causes out of bound memory access, which in turn invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: I think I understand better now, can you please expand a bit more about the "out of bound memory access"?

Comment: @Max Out of bound access means, you're trying to access memory which is not allocated. To simpify, you cannot access `persons[1]`, as c array index is `0` based. :-)